# Deep Learning Algorithm to Predict Bash Commands

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

Im new to machine learning, and I want to develop an application that takes all the data from multiple user's bash history, and predict the next command of another user based on other's executed commands.

I searched for it a lot but didnt find any good answer. Appreciate the ML expert's help if know about sample of similar code, or have any comments that might be useful such as what algorithm.etc. should I look into.

Answer (score 1):

You can check `Language Modeling` topic, which is able to predict the next word in the sequence given the words that precede it. You probably work with RNN or LSTM based networks for Language Modeling.